# Converting 8-bit two complement signed number to decimal

Tags: vhdl

The task is larger but I'm stuck at converting from signed 8 bit two complement number to decimal. Here is some code:

```
entity example is
    Port ( switches : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0) );
end example;
signal integer_value : integer;
```

Logic I'm trying to use to convert this input to decimal is

```
integer_value <= to_integer(unsigned(switches));
```

`integer_value` ends up being either zero or minimum value for integer (-2147483648). Example input would be "01101111".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `signed`, not `unsigned`, thus as:

```
integer_value <= to_integer(signed(switches));
```

Consider making a small test bench to experiment with the construction, so you isolate the problem, since it sounds like the issue is elsewhere in the design.  Simple test bench may be like:

```
entity mdl_tb is
end entity;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

architecture sim of mdl_tb is
  signal switches      : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
  signal integer_value : integer;
begin

  integer_value <= to_integer(signed(switches));

  process is
  begin
    switches <= "00000000"; wait for 10 ns; report integer'image(integer_value);
    switches <= "11111111"; wait for 10 ns; report integer'image(integer_value);
    switches <= "10000000"; wait for 10 ns; report integer'image(integer_value);
    switches <= "01101111"; wait for 10 ns; report integer'image(integer_value);
    wait;
  end process;

end architecture;
```

and this outputs:

```
# ** Note: 0
#    Time: 10 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /mdl_tb
# ** Note: -1
#    Time: 20 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /mdl_tb
# ** Note: -128
#    Time: 30 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /mdl_tb
# ** Note: 111
#    Time: 40 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /mdl_tb
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for the quick reply. I just tried `signed` and it didn't make any difference. The `integer_value` signal is 0 as per report from test bench.

Comment: Hi, test bench added to answer, and this shows that the conversion works, so sounds like the problem is elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Thank you very much. You were absolutely right! Problem is elsewhere, I'm still not sure where, but I've managed to eliminate this part as a point of failure.